# form action="/login"? What does the slash mean?

Tags: html, relative-path, document-root

`form action="/login" autocomplete="on" method="POST" class="Form__TBkbl6WYB9WAqzg-uU2EE"`

I expected to see something like `login.php` or some other PHP file.
What does the `/` mean?

Is this some form of security measure?

Answer (score 2):

The forward slash tells the browser to go to the root of the domain to serve the request. Without the `/` it goes from the relative path. Since there also is no extension it is likely mod_rewrite is being used to remove extensions. (e.g. https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ or https://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewrite+remove+extension)

If you have `example.com/account/` and used `login.php` it would serve from `example.com/account/` with the leading `/` it will serve from `example.com/`.

This provides no security and is only for cosmetics/functionality. No client side code is sufficient for SQL injection prevention.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a file login.php with this request inside.

Comment: Why is `login.php` required? How does this answer relate to the question of the `/`?